# Higher priority package is not selected

Tags: apt, 20.04, repository, pinning

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I'm trying to get the `mpv` package from the https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/ repository to be chosen over that of the [Launchpad ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests) repository, so far I did this :

```bash
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mc3man-ubuntu-mpv-tests-focal.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu focal main
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mpv-non-gnu.uvt.nl.list
deb https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal uvt
$ egrep -v '^(#|$)' /etc/apt/preferences.d/mpv 
Package: mpv
Pin: origin non-gnu.uvt.nl
Pin-Priority: 991
$ apt policy mpv
mpv:
  Installed: 2:0.33.0~focal1
  Candidate: 2:0.33.0~focal1
  Version table:
 *** 2:0.33.0~focal1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/mpv-tests/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.34.1+fruit.2 991
        100 https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal/uvt amd64 Packages
     0.34.1+fruit.1 991
        100 https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal/uvt amd64 Packages
     0.34.0+fruit.1 991
        100 https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal/uvt amd64 Packages
     0.33.1+wsl.1 991
        100 https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal/uvt amd64 Packages
     0.33.0+wsl.1 991
        100 https://non-gnu.uvt.nl/debian focal/uvt amd64 Packages
     0.32.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

The priority was successfully changed from **100** to **991** but as you can notice on the `apt policy mpv` output, the chosen **Candidate** didn't change to **0.34.1+fruit.2**.

How can I do that ?

Comment: the version from your preffered repo has lower versions nr. Try it with pinning over 1000 (1001)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update`

Comment: @nobody I don't get it. Is the **0.34.1** version lower than the **0.33.0** version ?

Comment: @mchid Yes I did :)

Comment: @nobody It seems setting the priority to **1000** solves the problem but it could be dangerous because `man apt_preferences | awk '/How APT Interprets Priorities/,/package/'` says `P >= 1000 causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a downgrade of the package`

Comment: yep, it would be better to remove some package sources for mpv.

Comment: @nobody Now, there is another problem : `apt list --upgradable | grep mpv` returns nothing.

Comment: Hm `sudo apt -s upgrade mpv` simulation first. Or `sudo apt -s install --reinstal mpv=0.34.1+fruit.2`

Comment: @nobody `apt -s upgrade mpv` works and says the package will be downgraded. Is this because there is a leading `2:` in front of the `0.33.0` currently installed `mpv` version ?

Comment: yes this is correct.